# Advanced Format Drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive

Bought a Samsung HD204UI today and downloaded/installed the Samsung Align Software as recommended by them for use with my XP. But the tools don't recognize my HDD as advanced format. Do I have to worry bout this? Will I have problems?

I tried to format the HDD using XP and win 7. The result is the same.
I try to put some files and no problems with it using both Xp and 7.

Answer (score 1):

A post by Dragonfruit
http://www.silentpcreview.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=59946&sid=cd3d9ee300b014974c9e507d17c76b63&start=30

There is mention of firmware problems in that thread also, you might return it and get another brand

Correct me if I am wrong, but after reading this article on 4k sectors:

I assume that it is possible to align Advanced Format drives (those ones, which are not provided with a special aligning software by HD manufacturer) for Windows XP usage with 3rd party 4k-aware partitioning utility:

> "The most critical aspect of a smooth and successful transition to 4K sectors used in Advanced Format is to promote the use of 4K-aware hard drive partitioning tools."
>   "When using third-party software or utilities to create hard drive partitions, check with your vendor to make sure they are updated and confirmed to be 4K aware."

So to align properly for Win XP usage for example Samsung 2TB F4EG HD204UI one has to find a 3rd party software tool for partitioning, which is 4k-aware, and use that software to partition such disk instead of Windows XP Disk Manager.

[Source of Information](http://www.seagate.com/docs/pdf/whitepaper/tp613_transition_to_4k_sectors.pdf)
.

So the problem could be how it was formatted/partitioned before you ran the align utility.

Samsung support is Horrid

Answer (score 0):

well, the 'align' software is required for advance format drives in windows xp. in windows 7 there is no such problem.

if the harddisk has been jumpered, align software may not be necessary.